# Prevent scrollbar from showing on top of elements

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have an element set to scroll and some layers on top of it.
The scrollbar shows over all the elements in front of the scrollable one.

It looks like this:

[image: Scrollbar appearing on top]

This is on Mac OSX Mountain Lion using Chrome 21.0.1180.89. Is there anything I can do or is this a 'feature' of Mac scrolling?

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't show your code

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS? My guess is that you need to change the height of the container using the scroll bar. Or change the overflow if it isn't meant to scroll.

Comment: Nothing to look at without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my first take would be to set

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on your container.